# Having trouble getting Google Drive authorization

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I have an Android app that I am trying to (re)implement Google Drive access for. The method I'm following is Google's migration guide to the update REST API [here](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/tree/master/drive/deprecation). I have my consent page set up properly, and everything works on the iOS side of things, so I assume at very least the credentials are set up properly.

I start with:

```
    GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(activity, signInOptions);
    Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = mSignInClient.silentSignIn();
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        // There's an immediate result available
        GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult();
        if (account != null) {
            setupClientFromAccount(activity, account);
        }
    }
```

If not logged in, I call this, which (successfully) launches the auth flow:

```
@Override
public void login(final Activity activity) {
    if (isLoggedIn()) {
        return;
    }
    Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = mSignInClient.silentSignIn();
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        // There's an immediate result available
        GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult();
        if (account != null) {
            setupClientFromAccount(activity, account);
        }
    }
    else {
        // The result of the sign-in Intent is handled in onActivityResult
        activity.startActivityForResult(mSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), REQUEST_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
    }
}
```

In my Activity I handle the result using:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && resultData != null) {
            handleSignInResult(this, resultData);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("Unable to complete Google sign-in (resultCode: %d)", resultCode));
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

which calls:

```
void handleSignInResult(Context context, Intent result) {
    GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result)
            .addOnSuccessListener(account -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult(): " + account.getEmail());
                setupClientFromAccount(context, account);
            })
    ...
}
```

Finally, everything comes down to:

```
private void setupClientFromAccount(Context context, GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    // Use the authenticated account to sign in to the Drive service
    GoogleAccountCredential credential =
            GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE));
    credential.setSelectedAccount(account.getAccount());
    mDrive = new Drive.Builder(
                    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new GsonFactory(),
                    credential)
                .setApplicationName("App Name")
                .build();
}
```

The problem is that this works just fine when I'm debugging, on my device. Once I deploy to Google Play, however, it fails. It goes through the authorization process, and logging shows that it gets to the `setupClientFromAccount()` in `handleSignInResult()`. But any Drive operations fail.

Now, that sounds to me like it may be a (re)signing issue, since that's the only real difference between the development/debug version and the release/Google Play version. But the credentials on the Google Play developer console are actually generated for the release key's SHA-1.

Am I missing something obvious?

(EDIT: Some further, ultimately unsuccessful steps taken to try to resolve this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817234/google-drive-access-authorization-only-works-with-direct-debug-build).)

Comment: define fails please

Comment: Sorry, to define "fails", my `Drive` object `mDrive` is gotten correctly (non-`null`), but `mDrive.files().list()` produces an `IOException` (as per the API documentation; just the API documentation isn't specific as to *why* it produces the IOException, that I can find). Again, this happens only in the Play Store version, not the debug version, which works fine.

Comment: Hi @KT_. Do you fixed your problem? I have the same problem. Maybe we will resolve the problem together?

Comment: @YuryMatatov I did eventually get this working, yes. If I recall correctly, in my case it was due to different signing certificates for the debug and release versions. I had to make sure that the credentials matched the build in the Google API credentials console. (I'm no expert, but that's my understanding, at least.) See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817234/google-drive-access-authorization-only-works-with-direct-debug-build).