# Google Drive access/authorization only works with direct/debug build

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api

I've been trying for a while to diagnose an authorization issue with OAuth 2.0, client ids, and Google APIs access (specifically Google Drive).

The general problem has been that things only work when building and running directly via USB on my device. I won't go into detail about the actual code — since I've done that [elsewhere here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60964590/having-trouble-getting-google-drive-authorization) — so I can focus on the current thing that will (hopefully) indicate to someone smarter than me what the problem is.

1. Originally I had an issue with not being able to get Google Drive authorization working at all when developing on my device. Then I figured out that's because Android Studio signs the debug APK with its own debug.keystore, and so I went to the Google APIs credentials dashboard and created additional OAuth2 credentials for my app package and the debug keystore (i.e., in addition to the existing ones for the app package and my release keystore). Seemed to work great.
2. Except release packages deployed to Google Play didn't work. They failed to get authorization, even after the user selected their account from Google's authorization flow.
3. My next idea (finally, after months of trying) was that my two sets of credentials for the same app package — one using the Android Studio debug keystore and one using my release keystore — were in conflict. So I figured out how to force Android Studio to sign debug builds deployed to my device with my release keystore, and got rid of the debug keystore credentials on the Google APIs dashboard. Everything seemed to work. Thought this had solved the problem.
4. Then, at some point last night, after uploading what I'd hoped was a fixed bundle to Google Play, my own device app updated from my directly deployed debug build to the Google Play version (because the versionCodes are the same? and the Google Play version gets preferred?) and...now it doesn't work. I get a — well, an obfuscated stream of W.System.err messages in logcat, since it's a Google Play APK, apparently.
5. When I deploy directly from Android Studio to my device again via USB, overwriting the Google Play APK, same versionCode, nothing else touched, etc., it works — at least until Google Play overwrites it again.

(EDIT: Confirmed...I can manually hit update in the Google Play app and it will overwrite my just-deployed-via-USB and just-working debug APK with the Google Play version uploaded yesterday, and Google Drive will no longer work.)

(EDIT #2: Also, I've double-checked, and the credentials in the Google APIs console are using the right SHA-1 signature. In fact, ever since I set up Google-managed signing, it seems that all three of my local release certificate and Google Play's app-signing certificate and upload certificates are the same, so there's very little chance of using the wrong one.)

What this means is that the only version of my app that can access Google Drive is the one built and deployed directly from Android Studio.

Does that suggest anything obvious?

Comment: Your question is not clear or specific.

Comment: If there's anything I can do to clarify or be more specific, please do let me know.

Comment: For example you say: "Things only work when building...". What things? 
Or "I won't go into detail about the actual code — since I've done that elsewhere", If this is the same problem you shouldn't ask a duplicate question with only different explanation. Merge them. Or "Does that suggest anything obvious?", is this your question? What is the main question? What exactly is the error, where? where is the code?

Comment: Anyways have you checked your Proguard File? You might need to `-keep` some classes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on improving the question. Well, I could go into detail about the code, which I've done elsewhere, in a previous (but related) question, but I feel that would distract from the issue at hand (and no one commented on code issues previously). As for "What is the error", there is none. It only happens with a deployed release APK, and therefore — as mentioned — logcat isn't available. By describing the general setup, situation, and behavior, I was hoping to raise a flag that someone who knew more than me would recognize.

Comment: And thank you for the Proguard suggestion, although I don't see anything in there that appears related.

Comment: From what I see in the sample app, It needs some proguard config. see: https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/tasks-android-sample/proguard-google-api-client.txt

Comment: If you don't provide the proguard, when you build the release apk, the "minify" feature will change the class names. This might be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you deploying to Google Play as an APK or a bundle (.aab)? If the latter, you might try doing a release as an APK, in case Google's re-signing is somehow a cause -- although I can't see how it could be. Note that I believe you'll have to upload your symbols separately in that case.

You can't change your signing certificates for a released app, so I wouldn't mess with those, but you might contact Google's signing support so at very least they can verify that there's no hiccup in the way things are set up on their end.